# First week of year considering the first day last year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following df:

```
time_series                  date   sales
store_0090_item_85261507     1/2020   1,0
store_0090_item_85261501     2/2020   0,0
store_0090_item_85261500     3/2020   6,0
```

Being 'date' = Week/Year.
So, I tried use the following code:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x + '/0', "%U/%Y/%w"))
```

But, return this df:

```
time_series                  date        sales
store_0090_item_85261507     2020-01-05   1,0
store_0090_item_85261501     2020-01-12   0,0
store_0090_item_85261500     2020-01-19   6,0
```

But, the first day of the first week of 2020 is 2019-12-29, considering sunday as first day. How can I have the first day 2020-12-29 of the first week of 2020 and not 2020-01-05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From the datetime module's documentation:

**%U:** Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

**Edit:** My originals answer doesn't work for input **1/2023** and using `ISO 8601 date values` doesn't work for **1/2021**, so I've edited this answer by adding a custom function

### Here is a way with a custom function

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
##############################################
# to demonstrate issues with certain dates
print(datetime.strptime('0/2020/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2019-12-29 00:00:00
print(datetime.strptime('1/2020/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2020-01-05 00:00:00

print(datetime.strptime('0/2021/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2020-12-27 00:00:00
print(datetime.strptime('1/2021/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2021-01-03 00:00:00

print(datetime.strptime('0/2023/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2023-01-01 00:00:00
print(datetime.strptime('1/2023/0', "%U/%Y/%w")) # 2023-01-01 00:00:00
#################################################

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["1/2020", "2/2020", "3/2020", "1/2021", "2/2021", "1/2023", "2/2023"]})
print(df)

def get_first_day(date):
    date0 = datetime.strptime('0/' + date.split('/')[1] + '/0', "%U/%Y/%w")
    date1 = datetime.strptime('1/' + date.split('/')[1] + '/0', "%U/%Y/%w")
    date = datetime.strptime(date + '/0', "%U/%Y/%w")
    return date if date0 == date1 else date - timedelta(weeks=1)

df['new_date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:get_first_day(x))
print(df)
```

**Input**

```
     date
0  1/2020
1  2/2020
2  3/2020
3  1/2021
4  2/2021
5  1/2023
6  2/2023
```

**Output**

```
     date   new_date
0  1/2020 2019-12-29
1  2/2020 2020-01-05
2  3/2020 2020-01-12
3  1/2021 2020-12-27
4  2/2021 2021-01-03
5  1/2023 2023-01-01
6  2/2023 2023-01-08
```

Comment: that requires modifying the input *before* parsing, no?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes this does your answer is the more easier way

Comment: ok seems the OP will require the one or the other work-around; both not "nice" ^^ btw. you don't have to use the `lambda`, pd.to_datetime is more readable and efficient.

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes I wanted to give a solution with minimal modification to the original code, but I'll add this one too since it is more readable.

Comment: @Vivian Oops forgot to add that part, you need to import timedelta from datetime, updated the answer

Comment: Yes, I'm running the code again importing timedelta.

Comment: @Vivian hi I just realised both our original answers doesn't work on certain dates, so I've made a custom function, this should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution can be used for any first week of any year?

Comment: @Vivian, I've just made one more fix it should work in any scenario now. I've tested with several cases as shown. You too can test it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) [parsing directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

date = pd.Series(["1/2020", "2/2020", "3/2020"])

pd.to_datetime(date+"/1", format="%V/%G/%u")

0   2019-12-30
1   2020-01-06
2   2020-01-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

you can also shift by one day if the week should start on Sunday:

```
pd.to_datetime(date+"/1", format="%V/%G/%u") - pd.Timedelta('1d')
 
0   2019-12-29
1   2020-01-05
2   2020-01-12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: But, I want the first day be on sunday, so I need 2020-12-29. Can I this?

Comment: @Vivian: ISO week starts on Monday, so you'll have to work around (see my edit).